# Autofac - How to resolve instances registered using JSON Configuration

Tags: c#-4.0, autofac, autofac-module, autofac-configuration, autofactory

Our requirement is to have different Logger instances for different user defined threads.

```
{
  "defaultAssembly": "Framework",
  "components": [
{
  "type": "SynapseMiddleware.Core.Framework.LoggerServicePerContext, Framework",
  "services": [
    {
      "type": "SynapseMiddleware.Core.Framework.ILoggerServicePerContext, Framework"
    }
  ],
  "parameters": {
    "loggerConfig": "18105"
  }
},
{
  "type": "SynapseMiddleware.Core.Framework.LoggerServicePerContext, Framework",
  "services": [
    {
      "type": "SynapseMiddleware.Core.Framework.ILoggerServicePerContext, Framework"
    }
  ],
  "parameters": {
    "loggerConfig": "18122"
  }
}
```

]
}

I created this JSON and registered it as a Module so that there is individual registration for each of the values - 18122 and 18105. But I do not understand as to how do I resolve them during runtime and where exactly.

I get 2 folders created but the logger does not write to its file, it writes to the other file as well.
in short, the instance that I get by resolving is not the instance for that particular value.

If I inject it in the constructor, only 18105 is getting resolved.

Could someone help please!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're registering two instances of the same service type and resolving just one - by type - so what you're saying is expected. You won't be able to do what you want via config like this.

Check out these docs:

- [Configuration](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/xml.html) - can tell you about what config can *and can't* do
- [Picking a service by context](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html) - explains ways to work around your challenge

Comment: I was going through the 'Picking a service by context' link that you have posted. My issue is that I am registering the same class as the same service but I want a way to identify each of them with a particular field, like a CustId or so.. Couldn't figure out much from there.

Comment: This is a multithreaded scenario. I am trying to register for each thread with the threadname as custid. @Travis Illig

Comment: Unfortunately I don't actually have time to literally write all the code for you. Think about using metadata to identify services, maybe that metadata matches the parameters. Maybe attribute filtering on metadata in constructors. Problem with trying to write all the code for complex app-specific answers like this is there's _always_ a "this works _except_..." and way more "free consulting" than was bargained for. There are docs on instance per thread. Docs on multitenancy. Docs on metadata. This is how you'd solve it in Autofac - using those features.